# Android mediaplayer stream recorded video from WCF REST server

Tags: android, wcf, video, streaming, media-player

Hey I'm struggling with a real hard problem for a few days now, hope you guys can help me.

my android app records videos and uploads them to my WCF restful sever, the server streams back the files. all is working well on firefox and chrome, the video is beying streamed without any problems.
on the same android application i recorded the video there is a problem, short videos (under a minute) are beying streamed without any trouble, yet when the video becomes longer the mediaplayer seems to not load it.

I have tried changing the mediarecorder profile fileformat and videocodec  yet no change, ive read mediaplayer only supports mpeg4 and 3gp video stream over HTTP and ive tried all the combinations.

```
   mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
   mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);


   CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);

   profile.fileFormat =2;
   profile.videoCodec=3;
   mediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);
```

im pretty sure my server handles the streaming well since its works on browsers, also other formats like audio 3gp and mp3 stream fine on the app only the video isnt streaming.

can somebody put me on the right track here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well after tampering around i finally found the cause to all this.
it seems the android mediarecorder appends the moov atom to the end of the recorder video yet when streaming with the mediaplayer the file must have its moov atom in the begining.

so there u go for anybody struggling with recorder videos not streaming back